# Python application which is running inside a docker container is not showing up

Tags: ubuntu, python, docker, container

I have created a python application using flask module and tested it locally and it is working fine. So i have tried to deploy it using a ubuntu docker container, but now the application is not loading from browser.

```
sudo docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name p-email-ubuntu-cont app-ubuntu-img
```

tried loading localhost:5000 and ContainerIP:5000 but none of this is not loading.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Sreejith
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y python 
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install requests
COPY MANAGE/ /home/deployment/
WORKDIR /home/deployment
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python ./manage.py
```

Any suggesions?

Answer (score 1):

Well a lot of things here the order of troubleshooting that I follow could be

1. Don't run your container in detach mode at least for your troubleshooting process (the -d switch)
2. Try to launch your container in interactive mode to see if you have some exception in your code or python installation using "docker run -i -t"
3. Run a bash session in your container "sudo docker exec -i -t app-ubuntu-img /bin/bash" whit the bash session try to run your code and see what happens

Comment: Thanks for checking this.
Issue got fixed. The issue was with host part mentioned in python code. I have changed from localhost to host="0.0.0.0"